# get sibling element text only when its parallel element meets a condition with xpath1.0

Tags: html, xpath

The goal is to get the code of the user named Nick who's title is Mr with xpath1.0.

```
<span class="user">
  <span class="master">
    <span class="user-title" title="Mr">
      <span class="name">Nick</span>
    </span>
    <span class="user-info">
      <span class="code">A</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
<span class="user">
  <span class="master">
    <span class="user-title" title="Mr">
      <span class="name">Bob</span>
    </span>
    <span class="user-info">
      <span class="code">B</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I would divide it into several steps to understand how xpath works in this case.

`//span[contains(., 'Nick'])` can get that node, but how to get the person's code info which is in next node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
//span
    [@class='user']
    [.//span[@class='name']='Nick']
//span[@class='code']
/text()
```

Basically this says:

- Find the user span that contains the name span with text Nick
- Within that user span, find the code span
- For the code span, return the text

Alternatively, you could directly navigate to the sibling element. However, it is not as readable:

```
//span[.='Nick']/../following-sibling::*[1]/span/text()
```

This says to find the span with text Nick. From there, go to the parent (the user-title span). Then go to the next sibling (the user-info span). Then get the span in there, which is the code span.

Comment: you could even simplify `[.//span[@class='name'][.='Nick']]` to `[.//span[@class='name']='Nick']`